# How to make scss grid like on the preview image?

Tags: css, frontend, css-grid, web-frontend

I am trying to create a SCSS grid, like in the image below. The issue is to calculate the 2nd and the 3rd columns. Do u maybe know, how to achieve that?

Thanks for any hints and help!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try making each line with separate classes

```css
.a {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
 width: 2px;
 height: 100px;
 background: black;
}

.b {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 80%;
 width: 2px;
 height: 100px;
 background: black;
}

.c {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
 width: 160px;
 height: 2px;
 background: black;
}

.d {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 40%;
 width: 2px;
 height: 100px;
 background: black;
}

.e {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 60%;
 width: 2px;
 height: 100px;
 background: black;
}

.ab
{
position: absolute;
top: 55%;
left: 52%;
font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>

<div class="ab">EXAMPLE</div>

<div class="b"></div>

<div class="c"div>

<div class="d"></div>

<div class="e"></div>
```

I know its pretty rough but it might help also you can use inspect element to change your code positioning in real time so that might help

Comment: Thank you, but as I wrote, it must be done with css grid. Do you know how to do that with display: grid?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this one:

```
grid-template-areas:
    "a1 b1 b1"
    "a1 b1 b1"
    "a2 b1 b1"
    "a2 b1 b1"
    "a3 b1 b1"
    "a3 c1 c1"
    "a4 c1 c1"
    "a4 c2 c2"
    "a5 c2 c2"
    "a5 c3 c3"
    "a6 c3 c3"
    "a6 c3 c3;
```

Give class to each element.
each "1" is with "a[num]",
the big "2.5" is under "b" and the third is "c[num]".

Comment: This will not exactly result in the same structure as requested. C3 is overrepresented resulting in a larger C3 section compared to the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the number of rows to allow for an even distribution of cells on the right.
Using 36 rows allows you to make the 1 cells 6 rows high, 2.5 is 15 rows high and 3.5/3 is 7 rows high.

```css
body {
    margin: 40px;
}

.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 5px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(36, 1fr);
}

.box {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #444;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 150%;
}

.col-1 {
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
}

.col-2 {
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
}

.col-3 {
    grid-column: 3 / 4;
}

.arow-1 {
    grid-row: 1 / 7;
}

.arow-2 {
    grid-row: 7 / 13;
}

.arow-3 {
    grid-row: 13 / 19;
}

.arow-4 {
    grid-row: 19 / 25;
}

.arow-5 {
    grid-row: 25 / 31;
}

.arow-6 {
    grid-row: 31 / 37;
}

.b {
    grid-column: 2 / 4;
    grid-row: 1 / 16;
}

.crow-1 {
    grid-row: 16 / 23;
}

.crow-2 {
    grid-row: 23 / 30;
}

.crow-3 {
    grid-row: 30 / 37;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box col-1 arow-1">A</div>
    <div class="box col-1 arow-2">A</div>
    <div class="box col-1 arow-3">A</div>
    <div class="box col-1 arow-4">A</div>
    <div class="box col-1 arow-5">A</div>
    <div class="box col-1 arow-6">A</div>
    <div class="box b">B</div>
    <div class="box col-2 crow-1">C</div>
    <div class="box col-2 crow-2">C</div>
    <div class="box col-2 crow-3">C</div>
    <div class="box col-3 crow-1">C</div>
    <div class="box col-3 crow-2">C</div>
    <div class="box col-3 crow-3">C</div>
</div>
```